# Mapping an SQL server library in SAS

Tags: database, sas, mapping

I'm trying to map the source of a dataset i usually access using SQL parse through as a library.

Below is the SQL parse through code I use to access the table

```
proc sql noprint;
  connect to ODBC (DSN='Location1' );

  create table test as 
  Select *
    from Connection to ODBC 
       (
         Select *
           from CentralDB.dbo.Table_i_want
       ) 
  ;

  disconnect from ODBC
;
quit;
```

And below is the libname statement I tried writing

```
LIBNAME mylib ODBC  DATASRC='Location1'   SCHEMA=dbo  ;
```

The above statement doesn't map it to the correct location, where do I put the CentralDB part?

Can anyone help me create a libname statement out of this?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the definition of `Location1` ? You probably want to use the `InitialCatalog` property in defining your data source.  If you can't you will have to use the libname init_string option to communicate a complete odbc connection string to the odbc library engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
libname mydblib odbc
   noprompt="uid=testuser;pwd=testpass;dsn=sqlservr;"
   stringdates=yes;

proc print data=mydblib.customers; 
   where state='CA';
run;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to create a view. The SQL statement already does that in a way. I want to create a library so I can view the entire database under CentralDB.dbo

Comment: Then you can try the updated one, in my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a metadata server: It is always better to ask your SAS Admin to register the library and tables you want want in SAS metadata / Folders so you will have a permanent and standard way to access them.

Quick Solution:

Use the libname below and update the schema, user and password

`LIBNAME mylib ODBC  DATASRC=location_1  SCHEMA=dbo  USER=sql user  PASSWORD="xxx"` ;

The step below will list the tables in the library

```
proc datasets lib=mylib ;
quit;
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't have the database=CentralDB anywhere? Where would I put it?

Comment: You dont need to add it, your data source location_1  will already have the database name. try executing the libname and let me know if you get error

Comment: It works but it doesn't direct me to the right database. DomPazz's comment has Database=CentralDB, i'm after something like that.

Comment: You either change the database name in the ODBC DSN or add Database=CentralDB , also make sure the user you are connecting with have the right database permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I always opt to build a connection string.  I don't have an example on hand, but you should be able to build a string that specifies both the database `CentralDB` and the schema `dbo`.

It will look something like this:

```
libname mylib odbc noprompt='Driver={SQLServer};Server=Your_Server_Name; Database=CentralDB;Schema=dbo;Uid=Your_Username; Pwd=Your_Password;';
```